# Why does RETURN shows different output in javascript

Tags: javascript, return

I am trying to solve a function that reverses the argument inputed.

So if I run the following code it works perfectly:

```js
function FirstReverse(str) {
  let a = str.split("");
  a.reverse();
  
  return a.join("");
}

console.log(FirstReverse("hello"))
```

But if I run the following code it wont work, though I would have thought it would be the same as the first code:

```js
function FirstReverse(str) {
  let a = str.split("");
  a.reverse();
  a.join("");
  
  return a;
}

console.log(FirstReverse("hello"))
```

So my question is, why would the second code behave differently than the first code?

Comment: `a.join()` does not mutate `a` - it returns a completely new array which is never used in the second case.

Comment: Two things unrelated to your question: 1) You should not start the first letter of your function with a capital letter. The convention everyone follows is that starting your identifier with a capital letter denotes constructor functions or classes, everything else is in camelCase with the first letter being lower case. 2) You can write that function much more succinctly by chaining all your method calls like this: `function firstReverse(str) { return str.split("").reverse().join(""); }`. Using ES6+ syntax, you could just write: `const firstReverse = (str) => str.split("").reverse().join("")`

Comment: If you want to do `a.join("")` without immediately returning the result, you can do `let b = a.join(""); return b;` (Or even replace the original `a` like: `a = a.join(""); return a;`).

Answer (score 5):

While `reverse` will *mutate* the array, `join` doesn't.

In the second example you ignore the return value of `join()` (which is a string) and return the value of `a` (which is the array) instead.